# Using reduce to add values of properties of a collection objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Pretty straight forward:

```
var bar = [
  { a: 10, b: 20 }, { a: 10, b: 20 }
];

var reduce = bar.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc['a'] = item.a++;
  acc['b'] = item.b++
  return acc;
}, {});

 console.log(reduce);
 {a: 10, b: 20}
```

I'd like reduce assigned the reference: `{a:20, b: 40}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum all properties of objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945388/sum-all-properties-of-objects-in-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general solution that will work even if your object inside your array contains different properties.

```js
var bar = [
  { a: 10, b: 20 }, { a: 10, b: 20 }
];

var reduce = bar.reduce((acc, item) => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)){
    if( acc.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        acc[key] += value
     }
     else {
      acc = {...acc, [key]: value }
     }
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

 console.log(reduce);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return a new object with added values.

```js
var bar = [{ a: 10, b: 20 }, { a: 10, b: 20 }],
    reduce = bar.reduce((a, b) => ({ a: a.a + b.a, b: a.b + b.b }));

console.log(reduce);
```

Or with a complete dynamic approach for all properties.

```js
const add = (a, b) =>
        Object.assign({}, a, ...Object.entries(b).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: a[k] + v })));
var bar = [{ a: 10, b: 20 }, { a: 10, b: 20 }],
    reduce = bar.reduce(add);

console.log(reduce);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than assigning the accumulator's property the item's property incremented by one, you should *add to the existing* accumulator's property value. You also shouldn't pass an initial object to the `reduce` given this implementation (or, if you do, you'll need to define the `a` and `b` properties).

Since you're using `reduce`, I think you should also consider using `const` instead of `var` - `const` is less bug-prone and easier to read:

```js
const bar = [
  { a: 10, b: 20 }, { a: 10, b: 20 }
];
const reduced = bar.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.a += item.a;
  acc.b += item.b;
  return acc;
});
 console.log(reduced);
```