# How can I sum total of this objects keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object

```
[
    {A: 47.5, B: 23.4, C: 32.4, D: 12.5, E: 18.2},
    {D: 10, C: 22.5, A: 85.7, E: 48.6},
    {B: 93.45, D: 37.1, E: 66.34},
    {A: 0, D: 0,  C: 0,  B: 8.50, E: 78.5},
    {C: 0, A: 0, B: 11.7, E: 0},
    {E: 89.4, D: 16.5, B: 29.7, A: 84.5}
]
```

I am trying some similar to this, but only works in order arrays, I need the sum of the key's now

```
const totals = new Array(StoreResumeRows.length).fill(0)
   StoreResumeRows.map((matrixRow: any) => {
     for(let index = 0; index < totals.length; index++){
       totals[index] += matrixRow[index]
   }
 })
 console.log(totals)
```

The output I need is like following

```
[{A: 217.7, B: 166.75, C: 54.9, D: 76.1, E: 301.04}]
```

Comment: what is your required result - it's unclear from the code you posted

Comment: This has nothing to do with react, so I removed the react tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum all properties of objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945388/sum-all-properties-of-objects-in-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate the objects in your array, using a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to add each value from those objects to the `totals` result:

```js
const StoreResumeRows = [
    {A: 47.5, B: 23.4, C: 32.4, D: 12.5, E: 18.2},
    {D: 10, C: 22.5, A: 85.7, E: 48.6},
    {B: 93.45, D: 37.1, E: 66.34},
    {A: 0, D: 0,  C: 0,  B: 8.50, E: 78.5},
    {C: 0, A: 0, B: 11.7, E: 0},
    {E: 89.4, D: 16.5, B: 29.7, A: 84.5}
]

const totals = StoreResumeRows.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => acc[k] = (acc[k] || 0) + v)
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(totals)
```

Comment: not all heroes wear capes, thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Try like below:

```js
const data = [
  {A: 47.5, B: 23.4, C: 32.4, D: 12.5, E: 18.2},
  {D: 10, C: 22.5, A: 85.7, E: 48.6},
  {B: 93.45, D: 37.1, E: 66.34},
  {A: 0, D: 0,  C: 0,  B: 8.50, E: 78.5},
  {C: 0, A: 0, B: 11.7, E: 0},
  {E: 89.4, D: 16.5, B: 29.7, A: 84.5}
]

const totals = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  Object.entries(curr).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    prev[key] = prev[key] ? prev[key] + value : value
  })
  return prev
}, {});

console.log(totals);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array, and see if each objects' keys exist, then add them to the result:

```js
const arr = [
    {A: 47.5, B: 23.4, C: 32.4, D: 12.5, E: 18.2},
    {D: 10, C: 22.5, A: 85.7, E: 48.6},
    {B: 93.45, D: 37.1, E: 66.34},
    {A: 0, D: 0,  C: 0,  B: 8.50, E: 78.5},
    {C: 0, A: 0, B: 11.7, E: 0},
    {E: 89.4, D: 16.5, B: 29.7, A: 84.5}
]

const res = {}
arr.forEach(obj => {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    res[key] = (res[key] || 0) + val
  }
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is broken. "index" is not your key.

```js
const totals = {};
 StoreResumeRows.map((matrixRow) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(matrixRow)) {
    totals[key] = totals[key] ? totals[key] + value : value;
  }
})
```